# Sql Synchronization updates newly inserted rows, how to differ new rows from old ones?

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

The title may be not very clear so here is the problem in details, I have sql server database provisioned and synchronized to an exact sql compact database.

scenario: in client database (sql compact) Store Table data is:
ID        Name
0         store1
1         store2

in server database (sql server) Store Table data is:
ID        Name
0         store1
1         store2

When I insert a new row at client with data ID=2 and Name= store3
and insert a new row at server with data ID=2 and Name= store4
and start synchronization what the data in both tables becomes

ID        Name
0         store1
1         store2
2         store3

while the scenario I want is to result

ID         Name
0          store1
1          store2
2          store3
3          store4

my question is, is this even possible and if so what is the way to tell sql that instead of updating one row with the other it should insert both new rows, any advice about my technique or code is mostly welcomed.

NOTES: ID is the PK column and it is a identity column.
the code used to synchronize is

```
    SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

        syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlCeSyncProvider("SyncScope", ceCon);

        syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("SyncScope", con);

        syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.DownloadAndUpload;

        ((SqlCeSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);

        SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
```

Please feel free to ask me for any more clarifications about the question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe use Guid as key instead of int IDENTITY

Answer (score 0):

your scenario would actually fire an Insert-Insert conflict. You can handle the conflict and manually insert the other conflicting row.

If you're early on your dev, i suggest you change your key to avoid PK collisions.

Comment: Thank you @JuneT I actually had to change my PK to avoid identity and enter it manually

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER like Primary Key will give you this operation.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little for the sake of OP?

Comment: Like ErikeJ said, using the standard SQL Datatype UNIQUEIDENTIFIER(GUID), it is not possible to insert lines whose identifier is not one of both sides (server / client) as (1,2 ...). 
ID will be more complex and the Sync Framework can distinguish the different lines

Comment: Thank you @AlTarba Unfortunately I couldn't get it right so I had to change my whole design to insert the ID manually and assign ranges for each client.